# How to enable ProGuard Minification for pure Java application?

Tags: java, proguard, obfuscation

An application is being obfuscated using ProGuard. Minification is intended to be enabled. The application is pure Java, how to accomplish this using `build.gradle`?

So far I have found only Android documentation on this. Usually it looks like this:

```
android {
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),
                    'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

There is also the flag to prevent shrinking in the ProGuard config, which I commented out:

`# -dontshrink`

Still, my code is being obfuscated, but not minified. All classes, even if they are not referenced remain in my JAR. How can this be resolved?

Comment: What do you keep off from obfuscation ? It may be one of `-keep` modifiers that effects and prevents unused classes from getting minified.

Comment: Everything that is not referenced should be removed. Currently I am checking the `-keep` instructions, however this does not seem to be the problem.

Comment: That's pretty weird. If you comment out all your `proguard-rules.pro` it'll try to obfuscate everything, can you check the diff between two outputs ? This way you can confirm if something in rules is preventing unused references from getting minified.

Comment: Yeah, that is how I am proceeding at the moment, however it is a large project, therefore there are many rules and testing is tedious.

Comment: Oh, though one. I can't really think of something else that may be causing it at this time, but if I bump up on something that may help I'll share.